# SET_DEFAULT for ForeignKey column itself

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, setdefault

I'm create this table in Django models:

```
class customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

> inviter is ForeignKey of self

Now I want `set_default` one row of customer table for `inviter` column.

Comment: So you need to point inviter column to Customer model itself, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `default` keyword

```
inviter = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=get_default)
```

and predefine [`get_default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#default) method.